# How can I add add features to SportsActivityLocation schema?

Tags: schema

SportsActivityLocation schema help please.

So, I'm pretty clueless about schema markup. I'm using RankMath and have created a SportsActivityLocation custom schema, but I'm trying to add additional items to it. This is for a sports directory, so the additional features I'm trying to add are sports offered by a league (sports), (features) like co-ed, men's, women's leagues, etc., and (category) like league, trainer, lessons, etc.

https://imgur.com/a/WW9s7z7

I've tried a bunch of different combos using amenityFeature, but keep getting errors when I run it through the validator.  I've included a screenshot of my latest combo, and you can see the error. My question is, what combo should I be using to be error-free? THANK YOU!